# Assignment operator as copy constructor

Tags: c++

Assignment operator can be used to copy the value of one object to another 
instead of using copy constructor,then why we required a copy constructor?

```
class example  
{
    int data;
public:
    example()
    {
    }

    example(int x)
    {
        data = x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    example a(50);
    example a(b);
    //same can be done with the assignment operator
    //b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The assignment operator checks for self-assignment, which in the copy constructor is not required. Also, copy constructor is normally used to define the assignment operator

Comment: Try to make a `const` copy of `a` using assignment, and consider non-trivial objects that are expensive to create and modify.

Comment: _why we required a copy constructor?_ we don't! And you didn't imlement one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bathsheba already said: A copy **constructor** creates a **new** object, an **assignment** operator assigns values to an already **existing** object. One needs to construct a new object, the other needs to handle whatever happens if you assign the values from one object to another. Take this example:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(int x) { someValue = x; };
    int getValue() const { return someValue; };
  private:
    int someValue;
}

class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar(int y)
    {
        myFoo = new Foo(y);
        myValue = y + 1;
        myInitDone = true;
    };

    Bar(const Bar& other)
    {
        //myFoo was not yet initalized, so no need to clean it up
        myFoo = new Foo(other.myFoo->getValue()); 
        myValue = other.myValue;
        myInitDone = true;
    }

    Bar& operator=(const Bar& other)
    {
        delete myFoo; // If we don't clean up myFoo here we leak memory
        myFoo = new Foo(other.myFoo->getValue());
        myValue = other.myValue;
        // myInitDone is only set during construction due to [reason]
    }

  private:
    Foo* myFoo;
    int myValue;
    bool myInitDone;
}
```

The copy constructor needs to set myInitDone (which is only done during constuction because *[insert reason here]*), while the assigment operator needs to clean up myFoo or it will leak memory.

Comment: @GoverNator there is no `myFoo` to clean up before `Bar::Bar(const Bar& other)` starts

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw in your assignment operator:  `delete myFoo; // If we don't clean up myFoo here we leak memory` -- What happens if the subsequent call to `new Foo` throws an exception?  You've corrupted your object.  In addition, there is no check for self-assignment in the assignment operator.  Prefer the copy / swap idiom, as it addresses both of these issues.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the self assignment issue, but I decided to leave it out for clarity's sake (i.e. to focus on the question of "why do we need copy constructors if we have assignment operators"). I also did not include a destructor (which also causes myFoo to be leaked). Regarding `new Foo` throwing an exception... in that case we have a problem anyway, as the object is stuck in a halfway state (imagine `myValue` being assigned before `myFoo`, so we now have half of `other` and half of *undefined*...)

Answer (score 6):

Because at the point of calling a copy constructor, the object being copied to doesn't yet exist.

An assignment operator assigns the value of another object to one that does exist.

Devices such as member initialisation can be used with a copy constructor, but are not available on assignment. Furthermore it's possible to create a `const` object using a copy constructor.

Furthermore, the assignment operator typically returns a reference to self.

So a copy constructor and the assignment operator *probably* will leave the mutated object in an identical state, but it doesn't *necessarily* have to be the case.